# Braintree - Determine If Payment Method Is The Default One

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

I'm currently using the Ruby `braintree` gem to get all the payment methods for a customer. Is there a way to determine if a payment method is the default payment method? Does Braintree provide that information through their API?

```
customer = Braintree::Customer.find(token)
payment_methods = customer.payment_methods
```

Comment: Their docs(https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/reference/response/customer#payment_methods) indicate that should work, so yes. What response do you get?

Comment: Ah, I see it has a `default?` method. If I inspect the response, it doesn't give me that information. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I work at Braintree. Yep, `default?` is what you want. Since you've figured it out, I suggest you post it as an answer (and let me know so I can upvote it).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @snkashis, I was able to figure it out. The following will determine if the current payment method is the default one:

```
payment_method.default?
```